# Running an Interstitial Test Ad on iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to show a test add on my iOS app after the main view controller appeared at-least 3 times. I have used the following code to run the add:-

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

var counter = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)
    
    if (interstitial.isReady) && (counter == 3) {
        
      interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
      interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
        
    }
    else {
        
        counter += 1
        
    }
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    
  let inter = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
  inter.load(GADRequest())
  return inter
    
}
```

But, I am not able to see the ad after I run my app. Could anyone please let me know what mistake have I made in the code and how can I correct it? Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `GADInterstitialDelegate` and present `interstitial` at this function:

```
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        if interstitialAds != nil && self.navigationController != nil {
            interstitialAds?.present(fromRootViewController: self.navigationController!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your AdMob ID in your `Info.plist`